# Mercurial won't send emails

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to make Mercurial on Windows send emails when I commit code. The Mercurial.ini file contains,

```
[ui]
username = PherricOxide

[tortoisehg]
ui.language = en
summarylen = 70
messagewrap = 80
closeci = False
engmsg = True
statustab = 0

[extensions]
hgext.notify =

[hooks]
changegroup.notify = python:hgext.notify.hook
incoming.notify = python:hgext.notify.hook

[email]
from = repository@company.com

[smtp]
host = inetmail.company.net

[web]
baseurl = http://dev/...

[notify]
sources = serve push pull bundle
test = True
config = \temp\subscription.conf
template = \ndetails:   {baseurl}{webroot}/rev/{node|short}\nchangeset: {rev}:{node|short}\nuser:      {author}\ndate:      {date|date}\ndescription:\n{desc}\n
maxdiff = 300
```

However, it never prints anything with test=True or emails anything with test=False.

A push shows,

```
C:\test>hg push -v \test2
pushing to \test2
searching for changes
1 changesets found
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
calling hook changegroup.notify: hgext.notify.hook
calling hook incoming.notify: hgext.notify.hook
```

And a commit doesn't seem to be triggering the hook at all,

```
C:\test>hg -v commit -m "test"
test.txt
committed changeset 11:a4ed0680b183
```

Does anyone with more Mercurial skills than I have any ideas on why it seems broken?

Answer (score 1):

Commit doesn't trigger the hook, only pushes to the repository will, that's what `changegroup` and `incoming` do.  You probably only want one of those two also.

What's in you `\temp\subscription.conf` file?  If youre `[reposubs]` or `[usersubs]` entries in that file are missing/wrong you won't get any emails.